# List append on for loop - Swift 3 / Xcode 8

Tags: swift, loop, lista, for, append

I'm having a problem adding items to a list inside the 'for' loop, where all items in the list are repeated with the last value entered.

Here is my NSManagedObject list

```
 var  listCursosNovos: [Cursos] = []
```

Here is my loop:

```
for i in 0..<JSON.count{
  var resultadoWS = JSON[i] as [String:AnyObject]!

  curso.codcurso = resultadoWS?["COD_CURSO"] as? String

  //Here I see that 'curso' comes as I wanted it  
  print("Add curso: ",curso)

self.listCursosNovos.append(curso) //Here is the problem
}
```

Each 'curso' item is shown to me on the console and everything works fine. The problem is that when I put this item in the list, it repeats the last value I entered. Example:

If I have 3 items within 'JSON' with the values:

```
{codcurso = "Zezinho"}
{codcurso = "Huginho"}
{codcurso = "Luizinho"}
```

After getting out of the loop and checking the result of my list

```
print("The final list is:",self.listCursosNovos)
```

They look like this:

```
{codcurso = "Luizinho"}
{codcurso = "Luizinho"}
{codcurso = "Luizinho"}
```

This is repeated regardless of how many items I have inside 'JSON' and the value repeated is always the last, I can't understand why

I hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Voce ta na pagina em português. Essa pergunta era pra ter sido postada na pagina principal

Comment: voce precisa criar um objeto novo (curso) cada vez que for adicionar ele no array dentro do loop. No momento voce ta adicionando o mesmo objeto no seu array 3x

Comment: @LeoDabus sou novo aqui e não me atentei a isso. E muito obrigado pela ajuda! Era isso mesmo!

Comment: Swift 3 no tipo do dicionário você deve usar Any em vez de AnyObject `[String: Any]` e de preferência usando conditional cast `as?` e adiciona nil coalescing operator no final `?? [:]` assim seu app não crash caso o cast falhe simplesmente ele passa um dicionário vazio.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @LeoDabus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a user here helped me, the solution was to create a new 'course' type object with each loop. I did not pay attention to this and was creating it before entering my loop

```
for i in 0..<JSON.count{
  var resultadoWS = JSON[i] as [String:AnyObject]!
  let curso = Cursos(context: contexto)//Here is the solution

  curso.codcurso = resultadoWS?["COD_CURSO"] as? String

  //Here I see that 'curso' comes as I wanted it  
  print("Add curso: ",curso)

self.listCursosNovos.append(curso)
}
```